# Created directories have the wrong permissions (get locked)

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I'm creating a log directory with a program that I'm writing:

```
def create_dir(dirpath):
    if not os.path.exists(dirpath):
        os.mkdir(dirpath)
```

When I run the program *sometimes* it will create the directory with a lock on it (according to my pycharm):

[image]
[image]

I've tried changing the mode to `0777` and `0o777` (default) however it still will create the locked file and force me to use sudo privileges to either read or remove the file. Is there a way I can create the directory without having having it lock on me?

Comment: Are you launching the application with the same user all the times (with the same permissions)?

Comment: @GendoIkari Yes. Just me on this computer, not running pycharm as root just as myself without sudo

Comment: so what are the file permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just works perfectly for me:

```
dir_path = "path/to/directory/including/directory/name"
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dir_path)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dir_path))
```